# How to change a link button's text on grid view when clicks on it

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have grid view with link button named 'CLICK'. when clicks on this link button I wants to change its text to "CLICKED" I have done like this, on row command

```
if (e.CommandName == "ARCHIVE") //FOR SETTING THE VIEW LINK BUTTON
     {

             LinkButton lnkbtn = (LinkButton)sender;
            lnkbtn.Text = "viewed";
            lnkbtn.Enabled = false;


     }
```

but its not working. please help

Answer (score 1):

Try like this...

```
if (e.CommandName == "ARCHIVE") //FOR SETTING THE VIEW LINK BUTTON
     {

             LinkButton lnkbtn = (LinkButton)e.CommandSource;
            lnkbtn.Text = "viewed";
            lnkbtn.Enabled = false;


     }
```

Comment: Good one and extremely simple

Answer (score 1):

Try this using javascript:

```
 OnClientClick="javascript:if (this.value=='Archieve') this.value = 'Viewed';else this.value = 'Bookmark';"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is:

```
if (e.CommandName == "ARCHIEVE")
    {
        LinkButton lnkButton = (LinkButton)e.CommandSource;
        if (lnkButton != null)

            if (lnkButton.Text.ToUpper() == "ARCHIEVE")
            {

                lnkButton.Text = "VIEWED";
            }

            else if (lnkButton.Text.ToUpper() == "VIEWED")
            {

                lnkButton.Text = "ARCHIEVE";
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (e.CommandName == "ARCHIVE") //FOR SETTING THE VIEW LINK BUTTON
{
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;

    LinkButton lnkbtn = (LinkButton)row.FindControl("lnkClick"); // LinkButton ID
    lnkbtn.Text = "viewed";
    lnkbtn.Enabled = false;
}
```

Reference - [How to get GridView's LinkButton ForeColor in RowCommand Event?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9514467/1099247)

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (e.CommandName == "ARCHIVE")
            {
                LinkButton lnkbtn= (LinkButton)e.CommandSource;
                lnkbtn.Text = "Clicked";
                lnkbtn.Enabled = false;
            }
```